# Diffie hellman key exchange on elliptic curve over an extension field

Tags: diffie-hellman, elliptic-curves

I am attempting to do a final semester project where I implement Diffie-Hellman key exchange on an elliptic curve over an extension field (2^256). Can anybody help me to generate the extension field for this project?

Comment: Ok, obvious questions - what have you tried and where are you stuck? If you're asking for us to implement the entire thing for you... we might struggle to do that, as you could be asking us to teach you quite a bit. However, if you've got to a certain point and are struggling with something - definitely [edit in](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/2318/edit) an explanation. To help you understand the problem with this Q as is, please see [this post](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/a/98/46).

Comment: @Amar: If it was you which did this edit I just approved: You can register an account (using the same mail address as you used when asking this question) and thus take ownership of your question again, allowing you to comment, for example.

Comment: What do you mean with *generate the extension field*? Implement it?